# Configuring cookies in Asp.Net Core 3.1 with Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm using Asp.Net Core 3.1 with Identity. And here is my all configuration in Startup class.
I'm trying to force the logged in user to logout if their accounts expired while using the app. I should configure the cookie correctly but i'm stuck on how to do this while having AddIdentity.

Here is my **Startup**

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 

        services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            //.AddDefaultTokenProviders()  
            .AddDefaultUI(); 

        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<EmailOptions>(Configuration);
   
        services.AddHangfire(config => config.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddHangfireServer();

        services.AddControllersWithViews(); //?
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); //?
        services.AddScoped<IExpirationJob, ExpirationJob>();
        services.AddScoped<IReminderJob, EmailReminder>();
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            //options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            //options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            //options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            //options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            //options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            //options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            //options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            //options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            //options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            //options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            //    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+ ";
            //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.Name = "my.Cookie";
            config.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
            config.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            config.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            config.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
        });
     }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment env,
        IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        //app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
        //{
        //    Authorization = new[] { new CustomAuthorizeFilter() }
        //});

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
      
     
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
      
        recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(
           "End Users Subscription",
           () => serviceProvider.GetService<IExpirationJob>().SetExpired(),
           Cron.Minutely
           );

        recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(
           "Send End of Subscription Reminder",
           () => serviceProvider.GetService<IReminderJob>().SendReminder(),
           Cron.Daily
           );

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            _ = ExpirationJob.SetExpired(context);//pass the HttpContext to SetExpired
            await next();
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Here is my **ValidateAsync** class

```
 public class ValidateAsync
{
    public static async Task ValidatingAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (claimsIdentity?.Claims == null || !claimsIdentity.Claims.Any())
        {
            await RejectPrincipal();
            return;
        }
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        if (user == null || user.SecurityStamp != context.Principal.FindFirst(new ClaimsIdentityOptions().SecurityStampClaimType)?.Value)
        {
            await RejectPrincipal();
            return;
        }
        async Task RejectPrincipal()
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **SetExpired** method

```
      public interface IExpirationJob
{
    Task SetExpired();

}
public class ExpirationJob : IExpirationJob
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly HttpContext _context;

    public ExpirationJob(ApplicationDbContext db, IEmailSender emailSender, HttpContext context)
    {
        _db = db;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task SetExpired()
    {
        foreach(var item in _db.Institution)
        {
            if (item.SubsEndDate != null)
            {
                if (item.SubsEndDate <= DateTime.Now) 
                {
                   
                    item.Status = SD.StatusExpired;

                    Guid securityStamp = Guid.NewGuid();
                    item.Admin.SecurityStamp = securityStamp.ToString();

                    _context.Response.Cookies.Append("my.Cookie", "expired");
                }
            }
        }
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding the business logic, you can get the `HttpContext` in the middleware, and modify the cookie value to force logout. Here is an example.

First, configure basic cookies in `ConfigureServices`.

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.Name = "my.Cookie";
            config.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
            config.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            config.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            config.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
        });
```

Second, configure the middleware.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
       IExpirationJob expirationJob)
    {
        //...
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.Use(async(context,next)=>
        {
            expirationJob.SetExpired(context);//pass the HttpContext to SetExpired
            await next();
        });
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Three, determine whether to overwrite the cookie by the expiration time `SubscriptionEndDate`  of the database.

```
public async Task SetExpired(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        foreach (var item in _db.Institution)
        {
            if (item.SubscriptionEndDate != null)
            {
                if (item.SubscriptionEndDate == DateTime.Today)
                {
                    item.Status = SD.StatusExpired;
                    Guid securityStamp = Guid.NewGuid();
                    item.SecurityStamp = securityStamp;
                    
                    httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my.Cookie", "expired");
                }
            }
        }
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Then, the cookie is invalid and this user will not access the resource.

[image]

Update:

An another method, if you want to pass the `HttpContext` to `SetExpired` as a parameter.

1. You can write a static class, like this:

```
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static HttpContext http { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Then, you can assign values to `http` in *Statup.cs*.

   ```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
       IExpirationJob expirationJob)
    {
        //...
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.Use(async(context,next)=>
        {
            MyClass.http = context;
            expirationJob.SetExpired();
            await next();
        });
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
   ```
3. Get it with this.

   ```
    public async Task SetExpired()
    {
        var path=MyClass.http.Request.Path;

        //foreach (var item in _db.Institution)
        //{
        //    if (item.SubsEndDate != null)
        //    {
        //...
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much @Karney! I really appreciate your effort. But here what I'm getting and I don't want to get into more issues, `ExpirationJob.SetExpired(context) ` this line throws "CS0120 an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property" & "warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

Comment: Also, Is it ok to add `(HttpContext httpContext)` in `public interface IExpirationJob{Task SetExpired(HttpContext httpContext);}`? Otherwise, it throws an error. And if I did this, This Job in Startup also will throw an error -> `recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("End Users Subscription",() => serviceProvider.GetService<IExpirationJob>().SetExpired(), Cron.Minutely);` Can I pass `(HttpContext httpContext)` also?

Comment: This may be caused by mutual references between static and non-static members

Comment: Ok it's resolved. But how can I pass `context` to `SetExpired` while it is not taking any arguments?

Comment: The context contains the current path and cookie. You can write a static class and assign context to static properties. This static class is set to be called globally. This is a method, you can change it according to your needs.

Comment: Still not getting this :( .. what should I do exactly ? How it was working in your machine without needing to do this :( ?

Comment: I have update the solutioin, please check whether it can solve your needs.

Comment: Appreciate your effort @Karney , But still I'm getting  `ExpirationJob Does not implement interface member IExpirationJob.SetExpired()`

Comment: Please do not use `IExpirationJob.SetExpired()`, you need to create an instance object, then reference this `SetExpired()` via the instance object.

Comment: @shahadalshuhail, please mark this answer. This will be my greatest reward.